# Anaconda Navigator PIP Python-Firebase Package Won't Install

Tags: python, firebase, pip, anaconda, installation

I am having issues with having Conda install the library at this link: 
https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase

I am running: `conda install python-firebase`

This is the response I get:

```
    Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
    Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

    PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

      - python-firebase

    Current channels:

      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

    To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
    looking for, navigate to

        https://anaconda.org

    and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Does anyone have a solution? I successfully installed it through `pip`, but I can't get the package in the `Conda` environment.

Python 3.7.4

Comment: Have you done any research? What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: Hint: https://anaconda.org/search?q=python-firebase

Comment: Well it seems that the package is not available. However, I was able to install it in the PIP environment. I guess I was asking if theres anyway for Conda to pull libraries out of my PIP env.

Answer (score 2):

Checking https://anaconda.org/search?q=firebase you can see that there is only one entry that has `win64` listed on the right side. Since you are running on windows, you need to select that one and then enter the correct installation command:

```
conda install -c nayyaung python-firebase
```

(Note that the channel `auto` suggested in other answers has only `linux-64` available)

As to your question from the comments:

> I guess I was asking if theres anyway for Conda to pull libraries out of my PIP env

I don't really know what you mean by `pull from my pip env`. If that means somehow pointing to the `site-packages` of another python installation, then no, this would be rather difficult to implement I guess. However, you can always `pip install` any package from pypi to your `conda` environments if they are not available for `win64` from the conda channels. Also [Read This](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) on using `pip` in `conda` environments

Answer (score 1):

You have to run this

```
conda install -c auto python-firebase
```

Take a look at [this](https://anaconda.org/auto/python-firebase)

Comment: I ran this as well.  I get the exact same error as above.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing `conda install -c auto python-firebase`
Check https://anaconda.org/auto/python-firebase for further information